# Does it matter that Unit Test project template in Visual Studio 2019 is for .NET Framework only?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing

I am creating a JSON WEB API with .NET CORE 2.2 and would like to add a unit test project. However, the only templates available for Unit Tests appear to be for .NET Framework only. Does it matter that the web API is for .NET CORE and the Unit Test project is for .NET Framework?

Per Microsoft: [Create a Unit Test project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/create-a-unit-test-project?view=vs-2019)

**UPDATE**

So, it appears that the answer is Yes, it does matter. When I tried to build the solution, I get the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Project '..*.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.2'. It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2'.    *_UnitTests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does matter is better to test with .NET Core. There are three Unit Test project types for .NET Core.

- MSTest Test Project (.NET Core)
- xUnit Test Project (.NET Core)
- NUnit Test Project (.NET Core)

Search when adding new project to find them.

Here is the documentation about [unit testing in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/) where everything is explained.

Comment: You posted an answer literally seconds before I posted the update. LOL. Thanks for the additional web reference. Any recommendations on which project type (i.e., MSTest, xUnit, NUnit) to use?

Comment: That depends on your preference which framework you like. If you are new to it I recommend xUnit which is the most modern and also used in the development of .NET Core.